How to get a closed-form for series $\overset{\infty}{\underset{n=0}{\sum}}\sin\frac{1}{2^n}.$
This question was asked by a friend of mine.
I can determine that this series
$$\overset{\infty}{\underset{n=0}{\sum}}\sin\frac{1}{2^n}.$$
is convergent, because $$\sin \frac{1}{2^n} \leq \frac{1}{2^n} \implies \overset{N}{\underset{n=0}{\sum}}\sin\frac{1}{2^n} \leq \overset{N}{\underset{n=0}{\sum}} \frac{1}{2^n} < \overset{\infty}{\underset{n=0}{\sum}}\frac{1}{2^n}=2$$ and $\sin \frac{1}{2^n}>0(n \geq 0)$, so this partial sum is monotonic increasing, according to the monotone convergence theorem, thus this series converges.
However, I am unable to obtain a specific value. I tried some methods, such as product-to-sum,attempting to eliminate adjacent terms, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. In the process of thinking, I thought of a problem I had dealt with before, $\overset{N}{\underset{n=0}{\sum}}\sin (nx)$,x is constant, I turned it into the computation of the imaginary part  of $\overset{N}{\underset{n=0}{\sum}}e^{inx}$, which is a simple geometric series.
So I attempt to calculate $\overset{\infty}{\underset{n=0}{\sum}}e^\frac{i}{2^n}$, but this seems to have made it worse.
So I would like to know how I calculate this series,I hope you can provide me with a good method,thanks!

What leads you to believe that we can give a closed-form expression for this series?
